# Responsive CSS Sprites in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a sprite image that I want to use. I can get everything working the way I want on desktop size monitor, but on smaller screen sizes, things go bad and the sprites do not respond.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/avEBqe) of what I currently have.

I tried playing about with:

```
background-size: options
background-clip: options
```

But still couldn't get it to work. My HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 orange">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>
    <h2>item-01</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 blue">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>
    <h2>item-02</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 orange">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>
    <h2>item-03</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 blue">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>
    <h2>item-04</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 orange">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>
    <h2>item-05</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 blue">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>
    <h2>item-06</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.img-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url('http://oi57.tinypic.com/15qtcv7.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.orange .img-wrap {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.blue .img-wrap {
  background-position: -155px 0px;
}

.col-md-2 h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Is there a way I can make sprite responsive? I tried Google, but nothing I found did it for me